# Secure Windows 7 that Auto Logs In

Tags: windows-7, login

I have a Windows 7 setup and every once in a while a program crashes. I have a batch file which reboots the machine and restarts the program. Everything works beautifully as long as I don't have a system password.

However if there is a system password everything stops. How do I get past the windows login screen in these circumstances and still have some basic level of security?

Right now I'm married to Windows so no, I can't switch Ubuntu.

I'm thinking about having the system ping me before the shutting down but that would still require me to use TeamViewer and log in and enter the password.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can't restart the program without rebooting?

Comment: You can set the default account and allow it to save the password but nothing about doing that is "secure"

Comment: Lock the computer in a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click Start, type netplwiz, and then press Enter.
2. In the User Accounts dialog box, click the account you want to automatically log on to.If it is available, clear the Users Must Enter A User Name And Password To Use This Computer check box.
3. Click OK.
4. In the Automatically Log On dialog box, enter the user’s password twice and click OK.

Source.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx

If you leave the system logged in as it is already, this is not much more or less secure.

Comment: thx will look into this.